# Collation on Bulk Insert

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, collate

I´ve been traying to fix a process for my company and I've found the source of my problem.

I have a CSV file from where I have to import some data, but some fields contains words with de Ñ word and SQL Server keeps replacing it with characters like this `╤` I changed my column collation to `COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS` but when I perform the Bulk Insert It doesn't care about the specified collation and replaces it anywhere.

Do you guys know a way where bulk inster respects the given collation ?

The code I'm using is below.

```
EXEC ('BULK INSERT #TMPP FROM ''' + @PATH +
    ''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'', FIRSTROW = 1, ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', KEEPNULLS);');
```

Comment: what's the DDL of #TMPP look like? You'll want that column to be a `NVARCHAR()`

Comment: `NVARCHAR(120) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS`  is like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, I needed to specify  `CODEPAGE = 1252` in the WITH clause. The code ended been up like this.

```
EXEC ('BULK INSERT #TMPP FROM ''' + @PATH +
        ''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'', FIRSTROW = 1, ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', KEEPNULLS, CODEPAGE = 1252);');
```

I hope you find it useful in the future.